# Change where an <img> tag holds the image

Tags: html, css, image

I need to change the `<img>` tag. Im making a script that expands to a larger image when I mouse over its thumbnail. I want it so that when the larger image appears its held in the middle of the image. Basically, by default it holds the image by the top left hand corner. I need it to be anchored (not sure if thats the correct term) in the middle.

Comment: Is there enough space to the left and top of the thumbnail for the larger image? What dimensions are we talking?

Comment: I'd recommend just using a library for this. Something like this: http://highslide.com/#examples

Comment: You're definitely reinventing the wheel here. There are many existing scripts that can do this, such as the one linked above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this jQuery plugin do the trick?

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

The Lightbox plugin is pretty popularly used for galleries that I think fit your description.